# Testing return value of AngularJS's .then() using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my AngularJS:

```
self.fetch = {
 things: function() {
   return $http.get("/things/")
     .then(function(response) {
         return response.data;
   });
 }
};
```

And this is my test:

```
it('fetch.things() should GET to /things/, success', function() {
    mockBackend.expectGET("/thingss/").respond({stuffs: 'stuffs'});

    var response = BaseService.fetch.things();

    mockBackend.flush();

    expect(response).toEqual({stuffs: 'stuffs'})
});
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Expected Object({ $$state: Object({ status: 1, value: Object({ stuffs: 'stuffs' }) }) }) to equal Object({ stuffs: 'stuffs' }).
        at Object.<anonymous> (tests/test_base.js:28:26)
Chromium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.102 seChromium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.119 secs / 0.102 secs)
```

What's that extra `status: 1,` stuff and where is it coming from?

Comment: `response` is a promise itself, not a result of a promise. Use https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your test;

```
it('fetch.things() should GET to /things/, success', function() {
   mockBackend.expectGET("/things/").respond({stuffs: 'stuffs'});
   var p = BaseService.fetch.things();

   mockBackend.flush();

   p.then(function(response){
      expect(response.data).toEqual({stuffs: 'stuffs'})
   });

   $rootScope.digest();

   return p;
});
```

Comment: It won't work. It needs $rootScope.$digest() to run the promise.

Comment: @estus it worked even without `$rootScope.$digest()`.

Comment: @Bulkan Thanks. this worked (without `$rootScope.digest()` or `return p`. With that said, what does `$rootScope.digest()` and `return p` do? And why is it needed?

Comment: @user2719875 `return p` is not needed (and it is total no-no if you use Mocha instead of Jasmine). This is how `$q` works, promise chains run on digest cycles, and `$rootScope.digest()` triggers a digest. The test obviously doesn't work without it, try `expect(1).toBe(2)` inside `then` and you'll see. The test passes without `$rootScope.digest()` because `expect` isn't executed at all.

Comment: @estus Hm, I actually did replace it to `p.then(function(response){
                   expect(1).toBe(2);
   });` and it gave an error `Expected 1 to be 2.` (this is without the `$rootScope.digest()`. You can try it on your end as well, it seems to be working.

Comment: @user2719875 I'm quite certain about things I'm talking about. This is a fundamental feature of $q. If you have different behaviour then your test differs from the one that was shown in the answer. It won't execute promise chain that was created after last digest (if there's no $digest(), it is flush() then). See http://plnkr.co/edit/te9sjI3EpP16HCB6S5r3?p=preview for example. That's why Jasmine promise matchers are good things, they save a dev from rookie mistakes.

Comment: @estus Okay thanks, so I changed it to your way and it works (injecting $rootScope then called $rootScope.$digest() at the end). Noting for future reference though, Bulkans answer doesnt seem to use $q (maybe thats why it works without calling $rootScope.$digest()).

Comment: @user2719875 Not because of that. Angular uses $q promises everywhere. As it was said, `flush()` triggers a digest. If you have it after `.then`, it will work, too.

Comment: @Bulkan I just realized that your code doesn't test what the promise returns (`response.data`), it just tests the parameter passed to `then(response)`. Is there a way for me to test that the `then(response)` returns `response.data`?